# Add event to another class button i

Tags: java, events, jpanel, menuitem

look, i did this:

i have one JPanel with menubar:

```
public class panelMenuBar {

    JPanel panelMenuBar = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu menuDistribuidor = new JMenu("Distribuidor");
    JMenuItem menuDistribuidorDistribuir = new JMenuItem("Distribuir");
    JMenuItem menuDistribuidorDeletar = new JMenuItem("Deletar");
    JMenuItem menuDistribuidorAlterar = new JMenuItem("Alterar");

    public JPanel montarPanelMenuBar() {
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0.1;
        gbc.weighty = 0.1;
        menubar.add(menuDistribuidor);
        menuDistribuidor.add(menuDistribuidorDistribuir);
        menuDistribuidor.add(menuDistribuidorAlterar);
        menuDistribuidor.add(menuDistribuidorDeletar);

        panelMenuBar.add(menubar,gbc);




        return panelMenuBar;

    }



}
```

and after this i add the PanelMenuBar to ANOTHER JPANEL in another class, but now i need to add Event for the MenuItems to change others CLASSES CONTROLLS, is this possible?

i made everything in each class to see how this works and of course make the code more easy to understand/read/fix

Comment: you should create at least getters for the menus you want to add events in other classes.

Comment: but is there a way to create a getters for the menuEVENT, i dont now

Comment: if you have access to menus from other classes, then you can add your event listeners there

Comment: i have but look, the event need to change ANOTHER class, CLass JPanel1 added to MainPainel, and when i click something change Class JPanel2(added in main too, but under Jpanel1), understand, thats my problem =(

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [JMenuItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) API, you will see that it is possible to fire an event for key pressed ( with `fireMenuKeyPressed(MenuKeyEvent event)`) . Also you could add in the another class a listener ( with `addMenuKeyListener(MenuKeyListener l)` ) for this events. Now all you need is to check if the fired event is for you. For this you can check the source supplied with the MenuKeyEvent.